# How to configure two internet routers on same network, one with VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have two routers on my network that each have a static address from a block assigned by our ISP. They both use the same internet pipe just at different static IP addresses. My wish is to setup one of the routers to support a VPN connection to a separate location and have everything talk to each other, i.e. printers, servers, NAS, etc. and also provide failover gateway support. I would like to hear some ideas on how best to accomplish this. Yes, I realize that only one router is required, but the first (main) router has some functionality that I want to keep that is not available on the second (VPN) router.

Comment: "_...provide failover gateway support._" It sounds like you need to use an FHRP (First-Hop Redundancy Protocol), like VRRP or HSRP, to give you router redundancy. It is unlikely that a consumer-grade router supports this.

Comment: If they both connect to the same internet connection, how is that done physically on the WAN side?

Comment: describe routers and gateway using IP addresses (not necessarily real)